# Generate JSON from SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server-2016

I need to generate JSON string from a sql table (using the `FOR JSON AUTO` qualifiers), while one (or more) of the columns is (are) stored as json string.

e.g.:

Table Persons:

```
First_Name    | Family_Name   |City      | Children
--------------+---------------+----------+---------------
David         |Bin            | Miami    |[{"First_Name" :"John","Family_Name":"Bin"}]
Mary          |Nis            | New York |[]
```

The required result would then be:

```
[
 {"First_Name":"David",
  "Family_Name":"Bin",
  "City":"Miami",
  "Children": [{"First_Name" :"John",
                "Family_Name":"Bin"}
              ]
 },
 {"First_Name":"Mary",
  "Family_Name":"Nis",
  "City":"New York",
  "Children": []
 }
]
```

My current issue is that in the result, all the occurrences of the `"` are escaped and hence the application receiving it fails (illegal JSON).

Could anyone suggest the correct phrasing for the `SELECT` command that would generate the result shown above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show the query you are currently using

Comment: SELECT  First_Name       ,
                Family_Name   ,
                City                   ,
                Children            ,
 FROM Person FOR JSON AUTO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
  SELECT        First_Name      , 
                Family_Name     , 
                City            , 
     JSON_QUERY(Children) 
  FROM Person FOR JSON AUTO ;
```